# Google.Apis.AdExchangeSeller.v2.0

Tags: google-api, adsense, google-ads-api

I'm trying to programmatically generate a DoubleClick AdExchange report. I am using the api client library from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.AdExchangeSeller.v2_0/

While the documentation is pretty straight forward when it comes to the standard fields, I cannot seem to find a way to get the Bid Metrics fields.

For example, in the query tool I can select the following:

[image]

However, looking at the Seller Rest API (https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/seller-rest/metrics-dimensions) The only metrics I can retrieve are the Standard ones on the left. How do I programmatically retrieve the Bid metrics?

Thank you so much in advance, I've been battling this all day :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not, the API only supports a subset of the UI, the metrics/dimensions available through the API are those in the link you included.